# Python: How to write a nested dictionary (dictionaries in lists in dictionaries) to a excel xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I am very new to Python and and i am looking for some guidance on how to create a *xlsx file from the following nested dictionary. I am aware that i have to use a package like openpyxl to generate the *xlsx File and that i have to use some nested for loops or a dictionary comprehension to get the Data. But i am not able to put all things together. Any Help/Tip is very welcome.

```
snapshot = {
  "SHAMk98bspucm02.some-domain.invalid": [
    {
      "Name": "SEP1CDEA7837E70",
      "Device Class": "Phone",
      "Model": 683,
      "Description": "+4912345556661 - BFE Alexandra Balzer",
      "Directory Number": "+4912345556661",
      "Registered On": "SHAMk98bspucm02.some-domain.invalid",
      "IP Address": "192.29.53.112",
      "Status": "Registered"
    },
    {
      "Name": "SEP1CDEA7837E12",
      "Device Class": "Phone",
      "Model": 683,
      "Description": "+4912345556662 - Michael H\u00f6nemann",
      "Directory Number": "+4912345556662",
      "Registered On": "SHAMk98bspucm02.some-domain.invalid",
      "IP Address": "192.29.41.111",
      "Status": "Registered"
    }
  ],
  "shamk98bspucm01.some-domain.invalid": [
    {
      "Name": "CSFOSTERAUC",
      "Device Class": "Phone",
      "Model": 503,
      "Description": "+4912345556663 - Christian Osterauer",
      "Directory Number": "+4912345556663",
      "Registered On": "shamk98bspucm01.some-domain.invalid",
      "IP Address": "192.28.11.13",
      "Status": "Registered"
    },
    {
      "Name": "CSFTHURNERF",
      "Device Class": "Phone",
      "Model": 503,
      "Description": "+4912345556665 - Florian Thurner",
      "Directory Number": "+4912345556665",
      "Registered On": "shamk98bspucm01.some-domain.invalid",
      "IP Address": "192.28.171.12",
      "Status": "Registered"
    }
  ],
  "skolrzucm03.some-domain.invalid": [
    {
      "Name": "CSFWIESBOMI",
      "Device Class": "Phone",
      "Model": 503,
      "Description": "+4912345556665 - Wiesboeck Michael",
      "Directory Number": "+4912345556665",
      "Registered On": "skolrzucm03.some-domain.invalid",
      "IP Address": "192.28.11.81",
      "Status": "Registered"
    },
    {
      "Name": "SEP6C6CD3A5C94E",
      "Device Class": "Phone",
      "Model": 684,
      "Description": "+4912345556666 - Nina Schraud",
      "Directory Number": "+4912345556666",
      "Registered On": "skolrzucm03.some-domain.invalid",
      "IP Address": "192.28.11.84",
      "Status": "Registered"
    }
  ]
}
```

The *xlsx File should look like the following:

```
|Name|Device Class|Model|Description|Directory Number|Registered On| IP Address| Status|
|SEP1CDEA7837E70|Phone|683|+4912345556661 - BFE Alexandra Balzer|+4912345556661|SHAMk98bspucm02.some-domain.invalid|192.29.53.112|Registered|
```

I tried the following code to get to the values of the inner dictionary.

```
for cm_nodes,device_info in snapshot.items():
    # print (cm_nodes,device_info) # Gets me keys and the values of the Outer Dict. Value is of type list
    for device_info_list in device_info:
        # print (device_info_list)
         for device_key,device_value in device_info_list.items(): # Gets me all the Dict Values of the inner Dictionaries
                print(device_value)
```

But now i am stuck. Questions i have:
- how to determine where a "device" starts ('name Key') and where it stops ('Status')

Comment: i am an absolut newbie when it comes to python and SO. So please bare with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the .xlsx generation I would use XlsxWriter and Pandas dataframe.
I assume you have this data in a variable named `dictionary`.

```
import pandas as pd

# Get the "outer" dictionary keys
outer_dict_keys = dictinary.keys()
# Define the Pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=dictinary["SHAMk98bspucm02.some-domain.invalid"]    [0].keys())       # It is quite ugly :D, just lack of time ... change it!

# Iterate through "outer" dictionary
for outer_dict_key in outer_dict_keys:
    # With this you get: SHAMk98bspucm02.some-domain.invalid, ...
    interior_dict = dictinary[outer_dict_key][0]        # The [0] is there     because it is in a list
    # Get the "interior" dictionary keys
    interior_dict_keys = interior_dict.keys()

    # This variable contains the data for one row.
    row = dict()
    for interior_dict_key in interior_dict_keys:
        # With this you get: Name, Device Class, Model ..
        row[interior_dict_key] = interior_dict[interior_dict_key]

    # You can reach the values like this:
    df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)

# Create an xlsxwriter object and save the created Excel file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('filename.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet_name', index=False)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: thanks for your info. i will give it a try and report back.

Comment: I had to tweak your code a litte bit. I changed the following:
````
    for outer_dict_keys,outer_dict_values in snapshot.items():
        for i in range(len(outer_dict_values)):
            interior_dict = outer_dict_values[i]
            interior_dict_keys = interior_dict.keys()
            row = dict()
            for interior_dict_key in interior_dict_keys:
                row[interior_dict_key] = interior_dict[interior_dict_key]
            dataframe = dataframe.append(row, ignore_index=True)
````

Comment: Theres only one issue left when ExcelWriter is called: Abstract class 'ExcelWriter' with abstract methods instantiated